# How to show that $M_2[A]$ is graphic but $M_3[A]$ is not?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, matroids

Here is the question I am trying to solve letter $(b)$ in it:

Let $A$ be the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$
For $q$ in $\{2,3\},$ let $M_q[A]$ be the vector matroid of $A$ when $A$ is viewed over $GF(q),$ the field of $q$ elements. Show that:

$(a)$ The sets of circuits of $M_2[A]$ and $M_3[A]$ are different.
$(b)$ $M_2[A]$ is graphic but $M_3[A]$ is not.

**My thoughts are:**

I know that a matroid that is isomorphic to the cycle matroid of a graph is called graphic. So, how can I find the cycle matroid of a graph in case of GF(2) and how can I negate the existence of such a cycle matroid in GF(3)?

Could someone give me some hints please?

Comment: This tag [tag:graphic-matroids] is not a currently extant tag on the site, and it is generally considered bad form to create a new tag without consulting the community, first.  New tags should be proposed in the [tag management thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35451/).  For further discussion, https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/tagging .

Comment: To find a graph in the case of $q=2$, observe that you can always use a connected graph. So maximal independent subsets correspond to spanning trees of the graph and you know already that such spanning tree has 3 edges, so  can do with 4 vertices and 6 edges for the graph. Start with a $K_{1,3}$  for the edges 1,2,3 and you can see that the placement for the edges 4,5,6 is forced. This will also give you a hint about the second statement about $q=3$